# Why can't you partially specialize a class member function?

Tags: c++, templates, member-functions, partial-specialization, class-template

Member functions of template classes can be fully specialized, e.g.

```
template<class A>
struct MyClass {
    // Lots of other members
    int foo();
};

template<class A>
MyClass<A>::foo() { return 42; }

template<>
MyClass<int>::foo() { return 0; }
```

would compile without problems.  Note that `foo()` is not a template function so this is not about *template function* specialization (I can understand partial specialization is not allowed there as it would become incredibly confusing in combination with overloading).  In my opinion, the above code is just a shorthand for the following template **class** specialization:

```
template<class A>
struct MyClass {
    // Lots of other members
    int foo();
};

template<class A>
MyClass<A>::foo() { return 42; }

template<>
struct MyClass<int> {
    // Copy all the other members from MyClass<A>
    int foo();
};

template<>
MyClass<int>::foo() { return 0; }
```

Is this correct?

In this case I'm wondering why a **partial** specialization with a similar shorthand is not allowed, i.e. why can I not write

```
template<class A, class B>
struct MyClass {
    // Lots of other members
    int foo();
};

template<class A, class B>
MyClass<A,B>::foo() { return 42; }

template<class B>
MyClass<int,B>::foo() { return 0; }
```

as a shorthand for

```
template<class A, class B>
struct MyClass {
    // Lots of other members
    int foo();
};

template<class A, class B>
MyClass<A,B>::foo() { return 42; }

template<class B>
struct MyClass<int,B> {
    // Copy all the other members from MyClass<A,B>
    int foo();
};

template<class B>
MyClass<int,B>::foo() { return 0; }
```

Since the 2nd fragment is legal and the 1st one would be completely equivalent to it (but without me having to explicitly copy all the other data members and maintain them in parallel forever), I don't see why the 1st one is not allowed.

I am aware that this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098758/why-cannot-partially-specialize-a-member-function-in-c-template) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920068/partially-specializing-member-function-implementations), but I am not looking for an answer of the type "Indeed it is not allowed." or "It is not allowed because the standard says it isn't.", nor for ways to circumvent this problem.  I am wondering *why* the standard does not allow it, i.e. is there a fundamental reason for this or could it be allowed in the future?  I didn't find this in any of the apparent duplicate questions so far.

Comment: this question is asked often. The long answer is here: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this article is about specializing *template functions*.  My question is about specializing *non-template* member functions of *template classes*, which in my opinion actually specializes the class rather than the function (since the member function is not a template).

Comment: MyClass<A,double> (for instance) is a different class to MyClass<A, int>. Attempting to specialise a template class's template type for a member function makes no sense.

Comment: Then why is it allowed with full specialization?

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense if you consider it to actually create a new class specialization as in the first 2 code fragments in my question.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your first question -- whether the second fragment is indeed equivalent to the first -- is "no".

In particular, your comment "// Copy all the other members from MyClass" doesn't really work: Those members have to remain members of a class template to ensure that they're only "instantiated on-demand".  Otherwise, you're likely to get spurious early errors on members you never actually used.

(There is also an unfortunate issue that in C++ not all implicit instantiations can be written as an equivalent explicit specialization.)

That doesn't mean we couldn't come up with a specification to add similar functionality.  It's just more subtle than "do the same as with full specialization", and so far I'm not aware of a serious effort to bring this to the standard.

Comment: Thanks!  But I'm a bit confused now - I thought all non-template members of a template class were instantiated whenever an instance of the template class is created.  Is this not true then?

Comment: Members are only "partially" instantiated with the class; i.e., the definitions are not instantiated; only the declarations. (And explicit partial/specialization only supplies definitions; it doesn't modify declarations.)

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that