# Why not allow partial specialization of template functions?

Tags: c++, templates

I could find some questions asking about why I cannot specialize member functions:

1. [Why can't you partially specialize a class member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397948/why-cant-you-partially-specialize-a-class-member-function)
2. [Partially specializing member-function implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920068/partially-specializing-member-function-implementations)
3. [why cannot partially specialize a member function, in c++ template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098758/why-cannot-partially-specialize-a-member-function-in-c-template)

But why does the C++ specification not allow partial specialization of template functions, when they are not necessarily members of a class?

```cpp
#include <array>
#define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)

template< int PathIndex, int PathLength >
constexpr const int findlastslash(const char (&path)[PathLength])
{
    constexpr const int end = PathLength - PathIndex;
    return (PathIndex >= 0 && path[end] != '/' && path[end] != '\\') 
            ? findlastslash< PathIndex - 1, PathLength >( path ) : ( end + 1 );
}

template< int PathLength >
constexpr const int findlastslash< 1, PathLength >(const char (&path)[PathLength]);

template< int PathLength >
constexpr const int startfindlastslash(const char (&path)[PathLength]) {
    return findlastslash< PathLength >( path );
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    STATIC_ASSERT( startfindlastslash( "cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp" ) == 17 );
}
```

```cpp
$ g++ -o main.exe --std=c++14 test_debugger.cpp
test_debugger.cpp:12:82: error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘findlastslash<1, PathLength>’ is not allowed
 constexpr const int findlastslash< 1, PathLength >(const char (&path)[PathLength]);
                                                                                  ^
test_debugger.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr const int startfindlastslash(const char (&)[PathLength]) [with int PathLength = 30]’:
test_debugger.cpp:21:5:   required from here
test_debugger.cpp:16:39: error: call of overloaded ‘findlastslash<30>(const char [30])’ is ambiguous
     return findlastslash< PathLength >( path );
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:5:21: note: candidate: constexpr const int findlastslash(const char (&)[PathLength]) [with int PathIndex = 30; int PathLength = 30]
 constexpr const int findlastslash(const char (&path)[PathLength])
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:12:21: note: candidate: constexpr const int findlastslash(const char (&)[PathLength]) [with int PathLength = 30]
 constexpr const int findlastslash< 1, PathLength >(const char (&path)[PathLength]);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
test_debugger.cpp:2:28: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
 #define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)
                            ^
test_debugger.cpp:21:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘STATIC_ASSERT’
     STATIC_ASSERT( startfindlastslash( "cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp" ) == 17 );
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:21:5:   in constexpr expansion of ‘startfindlastslash<30>("cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp")’
test_debugger.cpp:2:28: error: constexpr call flows off the end of the function
 #define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)
                            ^
test_debugger.cpp:21:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘STATIC_ASSERT’
     STATIC_ASSERT( startfindlastslash( "cppdebugger/test_debugger.cpp" ) == 17 );
```

While free function template partial specializations are not allowed, we can do an equivalent using class template partial specialization. A correct version of this example using class partial template specialization can be found on: [How to stop template recursion while using parameter deduction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472892/how-to-stop-template-recursion-while-using-parameter-deduction)

Comment: Because functions are subject of overload resolution and so you can have several function templates with same name that accept different arguments. Partial specializations just complicate it without any gain.

Comment: "loose functions" --> called "free functions" most of the time AFAIK

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? A simple "because that's what the standard says" answer? Something that quotes the part of the standard that says it? A reason why the standard says it? Something else?

Comment: @JaMiT, Just something that makes sense, i.e., a reasonable motive. For example, the impression I got was that the standard did not allowed it just because they said so or felt like (without any background/base). But as **`@ÖöTiib`** said, it seems it has a reason, the implementation or either will be too complex, or there is a direct conflict with functions overloading. This itself can be an answer, but if you can show an example of how this can be a problem, it would be awesome.

Comment: @user So reasons for the restriction, not necessarily the reasons considered by the standards committee. Hmm... may I suggest changing *"why I cannot partially specialize a loose (free) functions?"* to something more like *"what justifications can be given for the C++ specification not allowing partial specialization of function templates"*? (Sorry, I don't have a good answer.)

Comment: Essentially most if not all reasons you have found for member function should apply to free function and I would say even more given overloading which cause additional surprises depending if the partial specialization have been seen or not. Also there is an easy workaround as you can define a class and call it from the function. A few extra lines of code instead of make the language even more complicated.

Comment: Many of those questions link to this explanation: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm